# HAML: How do I generate a self-closing (href-lang) link tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need to generate this exact (href-lang) link  HAML:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://es.example.com/" />
```

This HAML code:

```
%link{href: "http://es.example.com/", hreflang: "es", rel: "alternate"}
```

gets converted to:

```
<link href="http://es.example.com/" hreflang="es" rel="alternate"></link>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: just one question... WHY?

Comment: Any problem with the second one? as i don't think that makes any difference

Comment: It's a task at work. To someone it seems to be important although I am aware that it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post what version of HAML you are running? Also make sure that your list of auto closed tags has not been altered.

I would also double check that your link tags are not just HTML5 "assumed closed" w/ no trailing `/` at the end of the tag.

https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#empty-void-tags-

Comment: It's 0.9, from what I see in the Gemfile.lock. Which list of auto closed tags are you talking about? I see there's a lot to learn concerning HAML ..

Comment: The gem is now on `4.0.7` I would suggest looking into why you are on such an old version.

Also I was talking about `Haml::Options#autoclose :autoclose` config. That is specific to newer versions of HAML however.